# generate, append and send string to another class using LOOP IN Java

Tags: java, loops, stringbuilder

I want to pass a series of the same string using LOOP from a method in Class A to  method in Class B. Below is my newbie code but unable to deliver. Thanks!

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class ClassA {

    public String ClassAMethod (String data){ 
       String theString;
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
        ClassA classA = new ClassA(); 
            int k=0;

            do { 
                k++;
                String generated = classA.generateString(data);
                builder.append(generated);
                 theString=builder.toString();theString+=theString;
                    return theString;   
                } while(k<5);
        }


    public String generateString(String genText ){
            genText = (UUID.randomUUID().toString());         
                  return genText;
           } 

}


public class ClassB {
    private static String data;

        public static void main(String arg[]) {
             ClassA classA = new ClassA();
            String sentString = classA.ClassAMethod(data);
            System.out.println(sentString);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an expected output, for the sample run of your program?

Comment: What is the purpose of passing `data` to method `ClassAMethod()`? You never assigned it a value, so you're passing a `null` value. In `ClassAMethod()` you then pass on that `null` value to `generateString()`. Why? You don't even try to use it for anything. --- Also, why are you constructing a new `ClassA` instance inside an instance method of `ClassA`?

Answer (score 1):

The main error is that you are `returning` from within your loop, what you want to do is returning after it.

Also as you are in `classA` you should not instantiate another `classA` object.

Try

```
   public String ClassAMethod (){ 
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();  
   int k=0;

        do { 
            k++;
            String generated = this.generateString();
            builder.append(generated);
        } while(k<5);

        return builder.toString ();
    }
```

**Edit**

As @Andreas metions above, `generateString()` does not need to be passed any arguments so change to

```
public String generateString(){
        return (UUID.randomUUID().toString());         
}
```